# Why is std::filesystem::copy() throwing a "generic: 2" error?

Tags: c++, c++17, filesystems

I've written a basic function which uses the `std::filesystem` to just copy all contents in a directory recursively to another directory. The code worked at first, but now broke out of nowhere and throws the following error when executing:

```
generic:2
```

My code:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

class backup {
private:
    fs::path location;

public:
    backup(std::string location_str) {
        location = fs::path(location_str);
    }
    
    std::error_code fetch_files(std::string src_str) {
        std::error_code err;
        
        fs::path src(src_str);
        fs::copy_options copy_opts = fs::copy_options::recursive | fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing | fs::copy_options::copy_symlinks;
        fs::copy(src, location, copy_opts, err);
    
        return err;
    }
    
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    backup example_backup("~/Desktop/backup_destination");
    std::cout << backup.fetch_files("~/Desktop/backup_source") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which OS? Linux? If so error 2 would be `ENOENT` suggesting your file/directory doesn't exist. Probably due to the unexpanded `~` in the file name

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm using macOS, so Unix nonetheless. What do you mean with "unexpanded"?

Comment: There is no folder called `~/Desktop/backup_source` on your computer, the shell expands `~` to `/Users/you/`, outside the shell you need to do it yourself (see the duplicates)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Oh, right. Thank you, that fixed the error.